# Tagging consecutive days

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands, greenplum

Supposedly I have data something like this:

```
ID,DATE

101,01jan2014

101,02jan2014

101,03jan2014

101,07jan2014

101,08jan2014

101,10jan2014

101,12jan2014

101,13jan2014

102,08jan2014

102,09jan2014

102,10jan2014

102,15jan2014
```

How could I efficiently code this in Greenplum SQL such that I can have a grouping of consecutive days similar to the one below:

```
ID,DATE,PERIOD

101,01jan2014,1

101,02jan2014,1

101,03jan2014,1

101,07jan2014,2

101,08jan2014,2

101,10jan2014,3

101,12jan2014,4

101,13jan2014,4

102,08jan2014,1

102,09jan2014,1

102,10jan2014,1

102,15jan2014,2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`.  For a consecutive group, the difference between the date and the `row_number()` is a constant.  Then, use `dense_rank()` to assign the period:

```
select id, date,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by grp) as period
from (select t.*,
             date - row_number() over (partition by id order by date) * 'interval 1 day'
      from table t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However im getting an error on date - row number

Comment: @user3694537 . . . I think the syntax is now correct for Greenplum.